# Issuing extrinsics Polkadot.JS/api using collatorSelection

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain-collator

I'm trying to utilize the Polkadot.JS api to query chain parameters and issue transactions under collatorSelection an example of which is:

```
const x = api.query.collatorSelection.candidates();
console.log(x)
```

This works when using the built in playground in Polkadot.JS/apps but doesn't work via api.  I am using v9.9.1 of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me (using the PolkadotJS API):

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api";

export const fetchCollatorCandidates = async () => {
    const provider = new WsProvider("wss://karura.api.onfinality.io/public-ws");
    const api = new ApiPromise({ provider });
    await api.isReadyOrError;

    const candidates = await api.query.collatorSelection.candidates();
    console.log(candidates.toHuman())
}
```

Output:

```sh
[
  'ofbMGzDpuJttjypUk7SsV4n1omwSxA2gKYXSEDM3gMahNuN',
  'op7G2ofug2Q2n1Bq3uUGzkNdSp68S93beMQkjjyDxnPREnk',
  'qyf2KVDbBmF3MjRgmyFpQrNUnoxhp9AWCJrywysQcwXaiyb',
  'raCf56Liw9dKJiqXSJMVoVV9eyV9s8DQoQD5r1TMcPoFM4B',
  'rwGFKTBauckjEieq3xauaiDXxjfarZ198KXXVZupa9Dr6xm',
  'sBwVWToF55CbuyBz3WEqDggniu8Gx18DkTQg4cagsCJsgVf',
  'sgxpvRrL2VpAqhLPqC9up2u7gf1pCpR9c8vB7XdxnBpjxUC',
  't4HMEqx3kW8ADAzKn5YWhAUQPdsZw7xFd39WLxRW193HYfh',
  'tbjKCiq9k2p6L4xLJ9H7mAHs8FBE76aG4KcDapUbUnifjnr',
  'tyBG83iCBH5zAx7zd3kvTzEJAGY8nuH2HsTtvf6YwCSwwVL'
]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Bruno.  My application used two api connections, one on the relay chain and the other on the parachain.  Due to my error I passed the relay chain api connection to a function requiring a parachain api connection.

Given the code above I established that functionality exists and was able to find the error from there. 

Thanks for taking the time.